# Doing a (Math) PhD abroad vs the same university

Tags: phd, early-career

I am a math masters student at an university in Germany, almost finished with my degree. I want to do a PhD and have the following options:

**Option A**: Do my PhD at the university I am doing my masters right now. I also did my bachelors here. The university is not considered very strong (it's not Bonn) but the relevant department got a lot of money from a grant for 8+ years and my advisor is a very renowned researcher in his field (which I am also interested in). He advised my bachelors thesis and I am doing my masters thesis with him. I get along with him very well. Also my support system (friends and family) is here.

**Option B**: Apply for a PhD abroad (in Europe). The obvious cons are that I probably have to learn another language, I have to put in time to find a new social circle and I may find myself with an advisor I do not get along so well. The pros would be expanding my network within math and do my PhD at a strong institute, which could be good for my career.

Some more information about myself: I don't have perfect grades but they are very good, my math grades are mostly perfect (it's my minor which doesn't have very good grades). I am not 100% determined to stay in academia after obtaining my doctorate but I want to give it my best and decide after.

I have trouble deciding which option to take. Obviously Option A is more "comfortable", but I am also unsure how important it is for a career in academia to do your PhD abroad. To me it feels a bit like a gamble, since I could land in some insitute, where I get a bad advisor and I am basically alone, abroad doing my PhD.

Comment: *"The university is not considered very strong (it's not Bonn)"* That sentence is a bit weird.

Comment: @JochenGlueck this was more meant as a joke, I feel like in germany only bonn is really regarded as a strong institute (as a whole, not just one department)

Comment: Depends what you are asking. Purely from an academic perspective, B is better. But you are a human first academic second, and if you human needs are better met by staying where you are, that it's okey and a reasonable and smart move to make.

Comment: At the PhD stage, the chances are you can get away without learning the local language, especially in Universities with a lot of international PhD candidates

Answer (score 15):

Other than the professional aspects, as an expat from Germany myself, I can unambiguously say that moving abroad (more than once) and getting to live in other countries has been among the most enriching parts of my life. In fact, most people living abroad will say that.

Of course, it's also hard in the beginning. You have find to a new social network, and learn to live with a different social system in which some things are done differently than at home (for example, in Germany I bet you never wrote or received a check, but here in the US people do all the time). But in the long run, it is *enriching* to your life, in addition to perhaps being good for your career.

Comment: This "personal development" aspect has been the main argument to consider option B

Answer (score 11):

Unless you plan to leave Germany eventually in any case, everything you say points to the current university and supervisor. It is not only more 'comfortable' but the other is risky as well.

The main reason for changing universities (my view) is that the current faculty no longer has much to teach you since they have already done what they could. Meeting others (home or abroad) has some advantage. But mixing language study with a doctoral research program doesn't sound optimal.

And not everyone gets to work with a renowned researcher with whom they get along well. Just an opinion, of course, but you have made the case yourself.

Comment: *"But mixing language study with a doctoral research program doesn't sound optimal."* May I remark that this sentence probably has a bit of US bias to it? For instance, the European Union has a population only slightly larger than the US (450 instead of 335 millions) but has 24 official languages. If you want to do a PhD as a, say, Slovenian, than your options are to do it at one of the three universities in Slovenia or to go abbroad. Learning a language during a PhD is quite common in Europe.

Comment: In addition to @JochenGlueck, it is often quite possible to get by with English only, especially in university towns. This depends heavily on the country.

Comment: @Jochen, I think other language refers to non-English. Of course science in almost all of Europe is done in English and you will get by at work only knowing English. If the local language is used for "Science" to for example the extent that papers are not written in English you should seriously reconsider whether what they are doing is really Science. The hard part of "getting by" is of course the personal/social life. There you're options might be severely limited by not speaking the language.

Comment: ... Oops didn't have space for the thing I was actually going to write. I'm from Europe. I moved to a country where I didn't speak the language for my PhD. And I agree with "mixing language study with a doctoral research program doesn't sound optimal."

I made some effort to learn the local language during the whole time I was there (as in a few hours a week). I never got to the point where I could use the language well enough to get by in a social setting. Learning a language can be quite hard and and so can doing a PhD be. Be prepared that you might not be able to do both at the same time.

Comment: @Kvothe: Please note that I didn't say doing a PhD and learning a new language at the same time were easy. I only said that it's rather common (which does of course not mean that everybody does it). No offence intended, but when you say that one will "get by at work only knowing English" you seem to be overextrapolating your own experience. Whether English suffices at work heavily depends on the group/lab. Some groups do a lot of their daily work in English. Some don't but are willing to adapt if one or several team members don't speak the local language. [...]

Comment: [...] Again others  might reluctantly agree to speak English to you all the time during your PhD, but will have most of their conversations in the local language, even if you are present (hence, you'll miss a lot of opportunities). I also know several German professors who insist that their international PhD students immediately start learning German. They simply enforce it by speaking more and more German and less English with the PhD student as time passes.

Comment: @Kvothe: Another thing is that some PhD students have teaching duties. Undergraduate classes are often taught in the local language.

Comment: I completely disagree with the suggestion that learning a new language while doing a PhD is a bad thing. Learning a foreign language while in the country where it's spoken is an excellent life experience, and although this takes daily practice, hours which are always scarce, I'd say a PhD is about the best point in an academic career for it: the time frame is just enough, but not so much that you can just keep postponing it; PhD candidates are typically neither too tied up in family nor side job; and it's a great concrete motivation for social interaction.

Comment: That said: it is _very_ common for foreign PhDs in Europe to always and exclusively talk English (or else to cluster together with others with the same country of origin and then talk in their native language). IMO this is a shame.

Answer (score 10):

If you seek an academic career in mathematics in Germany, it will be very useful to spend some time abroad. However, there is no particular need for this to be for doctoral studies, it could be as a postdoc instead.

Advantages of going abroad as a postdoc over going abroad as a PhD student in your case include the following:

- You can only be employed on temporary contracts at German Universities for 6 years post PhD. Doing a postdoc abroad makes the ticking clock for getting a professorship less harsh.
- A postdoc position is typically significantly shorter than a PhD, and leaving early isn't necessarily failure. This mitigates the risk that you could be miserable abroad.
- You have more time to built a professional network first, so that you know the mentor you'd be working with, rather than jumping in blindly.

Comment: Being of a suspicious nature, does 'you can only be employed on temporary contracts at German Universities for [no more than] 6 years post PhD' mean 'German law says, after 6 years on successive temporary contracts, the employer is obliged to offer you a permanent contract, and the universities are so keen to wriggle out of that obligation that they refuse to employ a postdoc for longer than 6 years in total'?

Answer (score 8):

Going for your PhD abroad (Option B) seems like a great choice. Yes, it's a bit scary to move, learn a new language, and find new friends. But, it's a chance to study at a top university, meet new people, and really boost your career. Sure, you're comfortable where you are, and you have a great advisor. But stepping out of your comfort zone could lead to big rewards, not just in work but in growing as a person. It might feel like a gamble, but taking this step could really pay off for your future.

In fact, many of the PhDs (in math) I met did a PhD precisely because they could have the chance to move to another country to experience a new life. And as an academic, you may find that you have to go to where works are instead of staying in your home country. Doing a PhD abroad is a good practice for living abroad.

Answer (score 2):

Two aspects:

1. As mentioned by others, moving to another country will always be beneficial. You learn new ways of doing things. And it's particularly "easy" for something like a PhD: in the worst case, you know that 3-4 years later, you can head back home.
2. In general, I recommend that students change universities or at least supervisors. Especially if you have already been supervised by the same person as both an undergraduate and an MSc student. We all have different ways of doing things and the same way as going to a different country will help you grow on a personal side, going to a different university or at least changing supervisors will help you grow mathematically.

2 is important, from personal experience. I did my two first year of undergraduate in one university, next two in another, my fifth year in another and my PhD in a fourth. All in the same European country. Then moved to another continent and did two postdocs in two different institutions. Altogether, worked in 6 universities (7 if we include my current one) and had 5 different advisors. All (unis and people) did things differently and I think that this makes me a more versatile academic and (I hope) a better advisor.

And I should point out that even if you are not considering an academic career, seeing different ways of doing things, supervising people for instance, is also useful in a professional environment: as a PhD, I imagine you would quickly end up having to supervise people even if working in a company. Work habits also change from supervisor to supervisor, etc.

One last point that may be worth considering. In math, more than one place have a "soft" (as in "unwritten") rule on not hiring their PhD students, precisely because they are looking for people that don't have the local institutional biases. So if you think you may be interested in a position where you currently are, it's a good idea to go elsewhere. (Not saying your university does this, but it happens often enough that it is worth bearing that in mind.)